# how to hide/show tag a after click on it that is outside of a div which become hidden and shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some html code with below structure. when I click on tag a with "moreCases" class,div with class "container-cases" is become show and when I click on "lessCases" div with class "container-cases" is become hide but tag a with "moreCases" do n't become show.how I can solve it?

***HTML:***

```
<a href="#!" class="moreCases show">more 1</a>
<div class="container-cases hide">
   <input type="text" />                 
   <a href="#!" class="lessCases">less 1</a>
</div>
```

***JavaScript:***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(".moreCases").each(function () {
          var more = $(this);
          more.click(function () {
              more.next().removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
              more.removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
          });
      });
      $(".lessCases").each(function () {
          var less = $(this);
          less.click(function () {
              less.parent().removeClass('show').addClass('hide');            
              less.prev(".moreCases").removeClass('hide').addClass('show');                                     
          });
      });
});
```

Comment: Where is your CSS code?

Comment: I dont have problem on css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to target the `parent()` before using `prev()`:

```
less.parent().prev(".moreCases").removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".moreCases").each(function () {
      var more = $(this);
      more.click(function () {
          more.next().removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
          more.removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
      });
  });
  $(".lessCases").each(function () {
      var less = $(this);
      less.click(function () {
          less.parent().removeClass('show').addClass('hide'); 
          less.parent().prev(".moreCases").removeClass('hide').addClass('show');                                    
      });
  });
});
```

```css
.hide{
  display: none;
}
.show{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#!" class="moreCases show">more 1</a>
<div class="container-cases hide">
  <input type="text" />                 
  <a href="#!" class="lessCases">less 1</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last `.addClass('hide')`

```
 $(".moreCases").each(function () {
        var more = $(this);
        more.click(function () {
            more.next().removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
            more.removeClass('show');
        });
    });
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ykjv8u75/11/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to iterate over the `.moreCases` & `.lessCases` instead you can simply add the click event to it. Beside since the click is on an `a` tag , prevent the default behavior by adding `e.preventDefault`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".moreCases").click(function(e) {

    $(this).next().removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
    $(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
  });

  $(".lessCases").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    $(this).parent().prev(".moreCases").removeClass('hide').addClass('show');

  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#!" class="moreCases show">more 1</a>
<div class="container-cases hide">
  <input type="text" />
  <a href="#!" class="lessCases">less 1</a>
</div>
```